# NSURLConnectionDataDelegate just work in App Delegate

Tags: xcode, ftp, nsurlconnection, nsurlconnectiondelegate, nsconnection

(in MAC OSX- Xcode) I tried to read file by FTP using NSURLConnection class, it is work fine just if my code in main Application Delegate class (AppDelegate) but if i using it outside (another .h .m files) the connection delegate not called.

Any help!?

here is my code:

```
-(void)getURL {

NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"ftp://.... connection string with file"]
                                          cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                      timeoutInterval:60.0];

NSURLConnection *connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
if (connection) {

    // Do something

} else {
    // Inform the user that the connection failed.
    NSLog(@"connection failed");
}
```

}

Delegates:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse  *)response
```

{

```
NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse");
```

}

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

{

```
NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading");
```

}

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

{

```
//Getting file data
[receivedData appendData:data];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the delegate `<NSURLConnectionDelegate>` to the view controller you are trying to use it in ?

for example

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <NSURLConnectionDelegate>
```

Comment: Yes i am, and as i said it is work correctly in AppDelegate class

Comment: for comment: i use it in MAC OSX not on iOS

Comment: @user2713544 I'm sorry, I didn't realize it was for Mac.